# Per-class constants in Python

Tags: python, coding-style

Another Python code style question.

If I have some "constant values" (quoted because there is not such thing in Python) that apply to a single class, what is preferred: module-level variables, or class variables?

E.g. Suppose we have a class `Counter` which does something when a constant threshold value is reached, which is preferred?

```
class Counter(object):
    THRESHOLD = 6
    ...

    def increment(self):
        self.val += 1
        if self.val == Counter.THRESHOLD:
            do_something()
```

or:

```
COUNTER_THRESHOLD = 6

class Counter(object):
    ...
    def increment(self):
        self.val += 1
        if self.val == COUNTER_THRESHOLD:
            do_something()
```

The only thing I've managed to dig up is from the Python docs. They suggest that class variables are ideally treated as "constant":

> Class variables can be used as defaults for instance variables, but
>   using mutable values there can lead to unexpected results.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

However, this doesn't really answer the question. 
EDIT: As @JBernardo pointed out, this is irrelevant, as it refers to mutable data types, not to mutable variable values.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: If only that one class needs it, putting it in the class keeps the module namespace clean. Note that you can access it via `self.THRESHOLD`, which will handle inheritance more neatly. Also, that quote from the docs doesn't say what you claim it does - immutability is not the same as being considered a constant.

Comment: I would agree with @jonrsharpe keep it within the class so it acts as a namespace and gives the constant context

Comment: "Mutable values" in this context is not "variable values". I means you shouldn't use lists and dicts (and many other mutable objects) unless you know what you're doing. Otherwise, always put the values inside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and the `self.` tip. I will leave the question a while longer to see what others think too.

Comment: I agree with @JBernardo, be careful while using with `self.THRESHOLD`, it first look for instance `var` and then class `var`, you can manipulate the instance var `self.THRESHOLD` while keeping class var intact

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definitely keeping it as a member of the class, it's clearer and tidier.

You can have multiple classes each with a threshold that you don't interfere with (not to mention global namespace references to a threshold). It's a lot clearer to read `classname.THRESHOLD` as that signals an actual meaning to the intent.

But also, it's much better for imports. If you use

```
from file import classname
```

You will only keep the threshold if it's actually in the class's namespace, whereas global namespace variables are ignored when importing specific classes/functions.

To demonstrate:

Classy.py

```
glob = "global"

class ClassName:
    name = "Class Name"
```

Otherfile.py

```
from classy import ClassName

print ClassName.name
print glob
```

Result of running Otherfile.py

```
Class Name

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\person\Desktop\otherfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    print glob
NameError: name 'glob' is not defined
```

Comment: Doesn't it break Open-Closed Principle? Let's say the constant is list of files on which class operates, and you want to add a new file. Having such constant in a class makes you alter the class in this case, even though class' logic hasn't changed.

Answer (score 5):

If it applies only to the class, it should be visible only to the class.